# How to run a Universal Windows Application as a daemon?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a C# Console application that needs to open and run a Universal Windows Application in the background. Universal Windows Applications do not have .exe's so I cannot seem to use System.Diagnostics.Process like I normally would with another exe. How can I open the Universal Windows Application from a Console application and read Debug.WriteLine from it ?

Comment: Does the app have to be a UWP? Why?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yes it does, because it utilizes Bluetooth Low Energy (Bluetooth 4.0) and to my best knowledge those API's only seem to be for Windows Universal Apps. Is there a way to use the libraries for Bluetooth Low Energy in a console app? (Maybe I'm wrong? This is what I am using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.aspx )

Comment: That page says "The Windows.Devices.Bluetooth namespace defines a set of Windows Runtime API that allows Windows Store apps and desktop apps to interact with Bluetooth devices" -- so it looks like "yes". The types also have the [dualapipartition] attribute, which implies desktop support.